Почему сервис запуская sh-скрипт не подхватывает значение переменной окружения?
Есть переменная, которая лежит  в файле /etc/environment
VAL_PUB="public_value"

Есть файл sample.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "VAL_PUB:" $VAL_PUB

Если зайти под пользователем и выполнить команду:
bash sample.sh

То значение выйдет, но если поднять сервис на FastAPI и кинуть роут, чтобы он выполнял этот скрипт, то при выполнении, он не будет видеть значение переменной VAL_PUB.
Почему так происходит?

потому что переменные среды не загружаются, в конфиге сервиса (если линукс то что то типа /etc/systemd/system/fastapi.service) в блок Service добавь строку EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment

@Mpmp, спасибо огромное - то что надо! А то я уже даже пробовал писать  там Environment="VAL_PUB=public_value". =))
